# update PDF file in Cloud Mysql

Tags: mysql, pdf, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I  am new to Cloud & Cloud MySQL .I have created a table USER_DTLS with 4 columns

```
CREATE TABLE user_dtls( userID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,userName VARCHAR(255), firstName VARCHAR(255),DOC_dtl blob,
    PRIMARY KEY(userID ));
    INSERT INTO user_dtls(userName, firstName) values ("00123", "XYZ");
    INSERT INTO user_dtls(userName, firstName) values ("00456", "ABC");
```

I have stored to 2 pdf file in storgae bucket .

File names are

1. 00123.pdf  2   00456.pdf

I need to update doc_dtl column with correponding file. What is right way to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how we can store a pdf in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785754/how-we-can-store-a-pdf-in-mysql)

Comment: I am lokking something like this. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/how-do-you-load-a-data-file-into-a-specific-field

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep the files into [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) ?

Each product exists to fulfill **one or more specific roles**, and in this case, [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) is the best option for storing media.

Storing media in [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/), even if possible, will sooner or later lead to cost and storage size issues.

**Cloud Storage** offers [multiple classes of storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) depending on the duration of retention (archiving for example) at very competitive costs.

In this case, simply store a `key` in the database and **name the file with this key** in Cloud Storage.

With `AppEngine`, `Cloud Function` or `Cloud Run` it's possible to access the SQL database and retrieve the media via `Cloud Storage` to serve it to the user for example.

Also, another argument for `Cloud Storage`: you can design a "reactive" architecture more like a pipeline of events, for example:

- user upload a new document
- an event is fired by `Cloud Storage`
- a `Cloud Function` is triggered by this event, and run a job on this media.
  ...etc...

Hope it will help you.